# How do I get data via an API using Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying angular for the first time to get a list of accounts from an API and display it in a simple list. The api is on a separate domain. So far I have the following in my app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myController", function($scope){
// when landing on the page, get all todos and show them
$http.get('http://api.example.com/accounts')
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.accounts = data;
        console.log(data);
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });
});
```

And my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script  src="app/app.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <ul ng-repeat="account in accounts">
        <li >
            {{ account.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

And a sample response.

```
[
  {
"name": "Discover",
"_id": "55d532da7fc30ff81f000008",
"__v": 0
},
{
"name": "Citi",
"_id": "55d6b9967fc30ff81f000009",
"__v": 0
 }
 ]
```

I don't seem to get it to work. All I get is a blank page and the console shows this error in chrome:

```
'mainController()' is not a function, got undefined
```

Comment: Any error in the console? Also are you using latest version of `angular`? If so, you need to inject `ngRoute` dependency in your app. :)

Comment: You should add $http as a parater in your function in controller

Comment: Yes I'm running the latest angular. Still figuring out error logs because I switched to a new IDE.

Comment: @AyoubOulaika Tried that and it does not work.

Comment: Open your browser console and loot at errors thrown! The `$http undefined` would have popped right out at you! Now you probably have CORS issues also

Comment: @charlietfl 'mainController()' is not a function, got undefined That's the error now.

Comment: Clean your cache and reload the page. That should fix this error.

Comment: @Maverick That wasn't the case unfortunately.

Comment: so where does `mainController` come from?....nothing like that shown in your code

Comment: @charlietfl Oops I meant myController.

Answer (score 0):

You controller should look like as below : You have missed some dependencies.

```
  myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope, $http) {
    // when landing on the page, get all todos and show them
    $http.get('http://api.example.com/accounts')
      .success(function (data) {
        $scope.accounts = data;
        console.log(data);
      })
      .error(function (data) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
      });
  });
```

There may be issue with cross origin request if your app and rest and on different domains.

Let me know the output in your browser's console.

Your application should look like as below :

```
  /**
   * @name myApp
   * 
   * Lets create angular application module
   * if second parameter is passed with enpty array [] or with dependecies , is    * called angular module setter
   * 
   * angular.module('myApp', []); Setter
   * angular.module('myApp'); Getter
   */
  angular
    .module('myApp', []);


  /**
   * Lets create controlller
   */
  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('myController', ['MainFactory', '$scope',
      function(MainFactory, $scope) {

        getAllAcounts();

        function getAllAcounts() {
          MainFactory.getAccounts().success(function(data) {
            $scope.accounts = data;
            console.log(data);
          }).error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
          });
        }

      }
    ]);

  /**
   * Lets create factory
   */
  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .factory('MainFactory', ['$http',
      function($http) {
        var factory = factory || {};

        factory.getAccounts = function() {
          return $http.get('http://api.example.com/accounts');
        };

        return factory;
      }
    ]);
```

HTML :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery@2.0.0" data-semver="2.0.0" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.3"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="myController">
    <ul ng-repeat="account in accounts">
      <li>
        {{ account.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Console says: 'mainController()' is not a function, got undefined